# Compare two values of different rows in 1 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I have the following **table A**

```
Skey    Rank
1001    1
1001    4
1001    0
1001    5
1001    rgvdv
```

Skey is not a primary key, but as per requirement Result should be based on skey

I want to write a query in such a way that gives the below result
**when Rank =1 , mark rank as average, If it is 1 and 4 and 5 mark as Best, last 1 and 4 is good**

So the above table data should result as

```
Skey   Rank
1001   Best
```

How can I do this in SQL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about other combinations?  1 and 5 or 4 and 5?

Answer (score 0):

I am  not sure I got it right but think you can use "Case ... When ... Then" pattern for this. It also provide to short table according to your ranks. I am writing a example query for you :

```
Select column_1,column_2,Rank,
(CASE
WHEN rank ='1' THEN
  'Avarage'
WHEN rank ='4' THEN
  'Good'
WHEN rank='5' THEN
  'Best'
ELSE
  Rank
END)
AS Rank_Line From Table_name desc rank_line
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But this will only cover for 1 single value. Same skey has to be checked by cobining the rows , That means , If same Skey =1 and 4 and 5 mark it as BEST

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Skey,
  CASE
    WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN Rank='1' THEN 1 ELSE null END)>0
     AND COUNT(CASE WHEN Rank='5' THEN 1 ELSE null END)>0
    THEN 'Best'
    WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN Rank='1' THEN 1 ELSE null END)>0
     AND COUNT(CASE WHEN Rank='4' THEN 1 ELSE null END)>0
    THEN 'Good'
    WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN Rank='1' THEN 1 ELSE null END)>0
    THEN 'Average'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
  END AS Rank
FROM A
GROUP BY Skey;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to assign based on the maximum *numeric* ranking.  That suggests:

```
select skey,
       (case max(convert(int, ranking))
            when 1 then 'Average'
            when 4 then 'Good'
            when 5 then 'Best'
        end) as rank
from t
group by skey
```